# Rails: How to store the parent data in the child model (association)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My models are as followings;

**models**

shop.rb

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
    has_many :items
    has_many :categories
end
```

item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :shop
    has_many :categories
end
```

How can I retrieve and store the `shop_id` in the `Item` when I save `item` data?

Although I think something like `@item.shop` works, I don't know how to apply it.

**schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160615060137) do

...

  create_table "shops", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "order_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "shop_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

...

end
```

**items_controller.rb**

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @item = Item.new
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)
    if @item.save
      flash[:success] = "item created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def item_params
      params.require(:item).permit(:name, :shop_id)
    end

end
```

**views/items/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@item) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit "Post" %>
<% end %>
```

It would be appreciated if you could give me any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in 3 ways,

**Dirty:** add a `hidden_field` named `shop_id` in the `item/_form` and assign the hidden_field to your value.

**Best:** Create nested object. In the route file do:

```
resources :shops do
 resources :items
end
```

It'll generate an `new` item path like `root_url/shops/1/items/new`. thus you can get the `shop_id`

**OR**

You can `create` the `new` item object with a `shop` like:

```
def new
  @shop = Shop.find(params[:shop_id])
  @item = @shop.items.new
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, @Emu. Although it works when I input the url directly after add 2nd your answer in the `routes.rb`, the following error was displayed when I added `<%= link_to "Add event", new_shop_item_path %>` in the `shop.html.erb`. The error is `ActionController::UrlGenerationError in ShopsController#show` and `No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"items", :id=>"23"} missing required keys: [:shop_id]`.

Comment: It works after editing as followings, @Emu. Thank you for your time. ` <%= link_to "Add item", new_shop_item_path(shop)`.